# Spring Boot File Upload - part is null after upgrade to Spring Boot 2.4

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I use multipart file upload with upload requests similar to the following curl variant:

```
curl --request POST 'http://localhost:8080/api/upload' --form 'csv=@"/path/file.csv"'
```

The form data looks the following when viewed in browser:

```
------WebKitFormBoundarysT6cYRLsXHQ8EWtZ
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="csv"; filename="file.csv"
Content-Type: text/csv
------WebKitFormBoundarysT6cYRLsXHQ8EWtZ--
```

My Java code looks like this:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/api/upload")
public ResponseEntity<String> upload(@RequestBody MultipartFile csv) {
    System.out.println(new String(csv.getBytes(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    return ResponseEntity.ok().body(null);
}
```

It used to work fine with Spring Boot 2.0 but once I upgraded to Spring Boot 2.4/2.5, the `csv` parameter is always null so `csv.getBytes()` throws NullPointerException.

What I've tried so far:

- Changing `@RequestBody` to `@RequestPart("csv")` or `@RequestParam("csv")` makes the upload request return HTTP 400 code with the message "Required request part 'csv' is not present"
- Adding `consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE` to `@PostMapping` makes no difference.

I've found out that by default Spring Boot uses `StandardServletMultipartResolver` because `MultipartAutoConfiguration` is enabled, it can be seen here - https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v2.4.13/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/MultipartAutoConfiguration.java

I've found a workaround - adding `CommonsMultipartResolver` as a default resolver instead of `StandardServletMultipartResolver` solves the issue. This can be done by adding a new dependency and a corresponding bean:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>

@Bean(name = "multipartResolver")
public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
    return new CommonsMultipartResolver();
}
```

However Spring discourages using CommonsMultipartResolver as can be seen at https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto.spring-mvc.multipart-file-uploads

> It is recommended to use the container’s built-in support for
> multipart uploads rather than introducing an additional dependency
> such as Apache Commons File Upload.

That's why I'd like to use the built-in support. Any ideas how to solve it?

Comment: try [https://www.baeldung.com/spring-file-upload](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-file-upload), Section 7. Spring Boot File Upload

Comment: Do you have spring-boot-starter-web dependency? I'm using @RequestParam(value = "csv") MultipartFile file and it works fine

Comment: @MarcStroebel thanks but both spring-boot-starter-web and spring.servlet.multipart.enabled are already in place.

Comment: @DeepanshuRathi indeed I already have this dependency in my project.

Comment: @lagivan I'm facing the same issue: "Required request part 'myFileName' is not present" after Spring upgrade from 2.3.5.RELEASE to 2.6.2. 
Any news on making it work with StandardServletMultipartResolver?

Comment: I encountered a similar issue in a spring upgrade from 2.0.2 to 2.6.2. In my particular use case I had code that built requests with a null passed as the file data in certain cases. As a result, I had to add a null check in my API controller to handle these cases. It might not be perfectly aligned with the question but, It seems spring used handle cases where file data was set to null, where now it's up to the controller code.

Answer (score 0):

Adding filter before authentication filter fixed issue for me. Works with  StandardServletMultipartResolver

```
public class HttpRequestPartsInitFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
    if(StringUtils.startsWithIgnoreCase(request.getContentType(), "multipart/")) {
        if (request.getParts().isEmpty()) {
            log.info("Request.getParts() is empty for={}", request.getPathInfo());
        } else {
            log.info("Request.getParts() is NOT empty for={}", request.getPathInfo());
        }
    }
    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

}

I've registered filter in security @Configuration class that extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .addFilterBefore(new OktaErrorFilter(LOGIN_URL, OKTA_ERROR_URL),
                        OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter.class)
                .addFilterBefore(new HttpRequestPartsInitFilter(), OktaErrorFilter.class)
                ....        }
```

I din't find explanation why this made it work.
Similar fix mentioned here:
[Spring POST multipart/form-data, request parts always empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70214698/spring-post-multipart-form-data-request-parts-always-empty)